# Query the ContentTypeId field using SharePoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, query

I would like to know if it is possible to query a SharePoint list using the ContentTypeId field using REST API. Can someone please help me on that? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to do a $filter query by ContentTypeId field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do a query using `$filter` expression you can to this like this:

```
http://{site}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{listtitle}')/items/select=ID,Title&filter=startswith(ContentTypeId,'0x01010028')
```